# view rendering issue with ajax call in django

Tags: python, ajax, django

I am trying to create a search form in django with ajax.Form is using the GET request.Ajax call is working fine,now main problem is with the Django View.I am unable to display results in django template section.
Here is my code:
**ajax call:**

```
    $("#search-form").on("submit",function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var form_data = $("#search-form").serialize();
    $.ajax({
        url : '/url',
        data : form_data,
        success : function(data){
            $("#results").html(data)
        }
    });
});
```

**DJango Template(Search.html)**

```
{% block course_nav %}
 {% include "./navbar.html" with active_link='jobs' %}
{% endblock %}

{% block SearchForm %}
<div class="row">
    <form method="GET" id="search-form" action="">
        {{ form }}
        <button  class="btn btn-primary search-btn">Search</button>
    </form>
</div>
{% endblock %}


{% block SearchList %}
<div class="row">
    <div id="results">
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

**Views**

```
def url(request):
    query = 'www.api-url.com'
    values = [request.GET.get(p) for p in ['title', 'location']]
    params = ['q', 'l']
    for i, value in enumerate([v for v in values if v]):
        query += "{}{}={}".format("&" if i else "", params[i], value)
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(query).read()
    context = json.loads(response)
    return render(request, 'app-name/search.html', {'response': context['results']})
```

I understand its very small problem but I need some help regarding the rendering of template using ajax in django.Because when it render it opens the search.html within search.html

Comment: json.loads converts json into python dict,so i am passing a dict to django template

Comment: first thing i would say is why are you rendering whole search.html and sending it. You should only render a small page containing result div. Also from your context form is missing so you might want to fix that also

Comment: yeah that's the problem it opens the search.html within search.html,so what do you suggest,i should render another template within search,html?

Comment: Why are you using Ajax here at all? If you just want to send data and render a template in response, that's exactly what a normal post would do.

Comment: I would suggest make a small template containing only results div and render it. I would better suggest just send json response why bother with complexity

Comment: @Daniel i am using ajax because i don't want to refresh the page

Comment: @Arpit ok i will try